# File association with electron builder

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I’m making a multi platform application with Electron and I’m trying to make the file association using electron-builder.

I’ve added it to the configuration and that works fine, when I double click on a file, it opens the app, which is expected, but I have no idea how to receive that file on my electron app, I’ve googled, looked issues on the electron-builder repo, but haven’t found anything. The only thing I’ve found so far is that you are suppose to handle that as a custom protocol, and makes sense to me if I want to open the file from a path or url, but I don’t understand how double clicking a file would trigger a custom protocol, does electron use a defined custom protocol when you double click a file associated with your app?

I haven’t found anything on the official docs neither, any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create your custom protocol to open your app like `myapp: --params` in your terminal and/or exec, is that what you want?

Comment: Well, not really, I want to be able to open an associated file (e.g. test.myapp) with just a double click, I've used file associations for that but I don't see a way to receive the file path on my app. I mean, i don't want to have to type the protocol to open a file, each time, i want to be able to do it by just double clicking on the file.

Comment: I'm currently also looking for an answer, and though I'm not certain, my _guess_ is that the answer lies within the NodeJS API which Electron is built upon. I would imagine that starting an app through file type association would be the same as launching the application while passing some arguments, so the file path(s) should show up in [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv). I just haven't gotten around to test this theory out yet.

Comment: Came across this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935292/argv1-returns-unexpected-value-when-i-open-a-file-on-double-click-in-electron?rq=1), and looking at the comments it seems my suspicion was correct. [`open-file`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-file-macos)(macOS specific) in the NodeJS documentation mentions using `process.argv` for windows.

Answer (score 4):

File associations with Electron works the same as for regular Node.js applications: you get parameters from the caller in `process.argv` [array](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

However, there is trick: when your application is packaged (that is, in an asar file), `argv` does not have the same number as arguments as when you run it in "dev" mode.

You can leverage `app.isPackage()` ([doc](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appispackaged-readonly)) to make the difference:

```js
if (app.isPackaged) {
  // workaround for missing executable argument)
  process.argv.unshift(null)
}
// parameters is now an array containing any files/folders that your OS will pass to your application
const parameters = process.argv.slice(2)
```

More details on this [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4690#issuecomment-422617581).