# Argv[1] returns unexpected value when I open a file on double click in Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to open a file on double click. The file is being built for the Mac App Store using electron-packager.

I have things set up so that my electron app opens when the file is double clicked, however the filename of the double clicked file is not passed to the app in the command line parameters.

The data being returned for argv[0] is the app path (as expected), and for argv[1] is something similar to -psn_0_857362. I was under the impressions argv[1] would be the path to the requested file, which is what I am looking for.

A simplified version of the code I am using (in main.js) is:

```
ipcMain.on(
'getOpenFile',
function( e ) {

    let data = null;

    if ( process.argv.length >= 2 ) {
        data = process.argv[1];
    }

    e.returnValue = data;

}
);
```

Why is it not displaying the path? Is this not possible with the mac app store or do I need to do something else to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On macOS, you may have to listen to the [app](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app) event [open-file](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-file-macos) from the main process:

```
app.on('open-file', (event, path) =>
{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(path);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Opening the file works fine. The problem is accessing the filepath when I double click an associated file. I shall update the question to clarify this.

Comment: The description of the [event 'open-file'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-file-macos) for macOS states that "On Windows, you have to parse process.argv (in the main process) to get the filepath."; so, on macOS, listening to this event may be the only way to get the opened file path...

Comment: oh - interesting. Thanks. I did try it after you mentioned it but had no luck. I shall dig a bit deeper and try again.

Comment: You were right - thanks! When I tested it I swapped app.on for mainWindow.on since that's what all the other events I am using use. Rookie mistake. It's working now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad it works! ^_^ BTW, the event description also states an important point: "open-file is also emitted when a file is dropped onto the dock and the application is not yet running. Make sure to listen for the open-file event very early in your application startup to handle this case (even before the ready event is emitted)."